# Mysql sort date format

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, datetime

I have an unavoidable situation where the dates are stored in UK date format, e.g.:

```
31/12/2001  00:00:00
```

I need it in descending order, I've tried this but it errors

```sql
select *, DATE_FORMAT(completiondate,'\%e/%c/%Y\') as cdate 
from projects 
where countries = 1 
order by cdate desc
```

Error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   the right syntax to use near '' order by cdate desc'

I'm using MySQL 4.1.9

Comment: Does it work without the `order by` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping the `%` character unnecessarily. But the actual problem is that that you have an un-terminated string literal in your query:

```
-- this does not terminate the string ----------v
select *, DATE_FORMAT(completiondate,'\%e/%c/%Y\') as cdate
from projects
where countries = 1
order by cdate desc
```

Change to:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(completiondate,'%e/%c/%Y') AS cdate
FROM projects
WHERE countries = 1
ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

This was the end solution

```
select *,completiondate from projects order by str_to_date(completiondate,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Jim, your end solution was a huge help for me. My dates are in the 02/28/2013 format. I used the code:

```
SELECT *,str_to_date(SaleDate,'%m/%d/%Y') AS cdate FROM mytable ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE countries = 1 order by cdate desc
```

I'm guessing you have cdate already in your database? If so, you don't need to set "date_format" since it's already there.
But I may be wrong since I've never used 4.1.9

Comment: OP needs to convert the date because the column is a (var)char instead of datetime